# "threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler"

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am running into what looks like a common problem. However, the solution often suggested doesn't seem to work here. I am getting "threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler" when trying to run App Engine. Of course, the documentation is horrible. I am using webapp2, so the threadsafe shouldn't matter.

My file structure should be as follows:
backend/api/get_json.py - This serves all HTTP requests coming to /api/*.json In other words, the backend/ section is hidden from the end user.

I am having trouble getting the app.yaml to recognize and properly load the Python file at /backend/api/get_json.py

app.yaml file:

```
application: ebtest
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /api/.*\.json
  script: backend/api/get_json.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

backend/api/get_json.py

```
import webapp2

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'
        self.response.write('Hello, World!')


application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/api/get_users.json', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

Errors

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/yaml_listener.py", line 177, in _HandleEvents
    raise yaml_errors.EventError(e, event_object)
google.appengine.api.yaml_errors.EventError: **threadsafe cannot be enabled with CGI handler: backend/api/get_json.application**
```

Comment: is threadsafe not supposed to be true instead of yes? also I don't think you need to specify webapp2 in the libraries. At least that's what I have in my application

Comment: i think it should be true now that i look at documentation; unfortunately, that doesn't fix the problem. I updated the code offline and in the snippet above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works for me.. here is my app.yaml (I combined it with helloworld example) I don't get any error on starting dev_appserver on localhost. What version of appengine do you use? I'm using 1.7.5

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

libraries:
- name: django
  version: "1.2"
- name: pycrypto
  version: "2.6"


handlers:
- url: /api/.*\.json
  script: backend.api.get_json.application
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.app
```

You need to create

```
__init__.py
```

inside the backend and the api folder

Comment: Can you share your file structure? i have get_json not in the root? I have it in backend/api/get_json.py ? How do I do the file structure?                In other words, you have "script: get_json.application" but I have get_json nested in backend/api/get_json.py ... how do I keep my file structure?

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't aware you need to keep the structure. I've changed my answer